# Encapsulating and mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, encapsulation

Suppose I have class with simple dependency:

```
public interface Dependency {
    int doSomething(int value);
    void doMore(int value);
    int doALotMore(int value);
}

public final class A implements SomeInterface {
    private final Dependency dep;

    public A (Dependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    @Override
    public int add(final int x) {
        dep.doMore(x);
        return x + dep.doSomething(x) + dep.doALotMore(x);
    }
}
```

And I'm writing test using mocks:

```
public class TestA {
    private Dependency mockDep;
    private SomeInterface a;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockDep = Mockito.mock(Dependency.class);
        a = new A(mockDep);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAdd() {
        final int x = 5;
        when(mockDep.doSomething(x)).thenReturn(6);
        when(mockDep.doALotMore(x)).thenReturn(7);

        int actual = a.add(x);

        assertThat(actual, is(18));

        verify(mockDep, times(1)).doSomething();
        verify(mockDep, times(1)).doALotMore();
        verify(mockDep, times(1)).doMore();

        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockDep);
    }
}
```

So far so good.

So the question is: do we violate encapsulation of class `A` by verifying how exactly the dependency was used? Does it really needed to test that dependency was used in exactly that way? Shouldn't we test `A` like a black-box (delete `verify` invocations from test case and leave just `assertThat`)? And how to deal with dependencies in such case?

The reason I'm asking is that I caught myself writing good amount of verification dependency code and it seems that we start to test actual internal realization details about class. And I feel uncomfortable about that because when I will try to rewrite this realization details in another way I need to rewrite test cases although the result of `add` for example will be the same. If I would test my class as a black-box I can change realization details and still be sure that given input will give same output.

Or it is necessary to actually test exactly the realization details and that is the point of unit-test itself? It seems somewhat wrong for me.

Consider this test instead:

```
 public class TestA {
    private Dependency mockDep;
    private SomeInterface a;
    private final int x = 5;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockDep = Mockito.mock(Dependency.class);
        a = new A(mockDep);

        when(mockDep.doSomething(x)).thenReturn(6);
        when(mockDep.doALotMore(x)).thenReturn(7);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAdd() {
        int actual = a.add(x);

        assertThat(actual, is(18));
    }
}
```

Comment: If `A#add(int)` is defined as a method which add the result of a specific method call to `x` itself, when it is fine to test that it actually called that method and added it to `x`. _When_ and _where_ `add` calls the method of the dependent class actually doesn't matter for your test and you don't test that anyway (in your example here). Thus that test looks fine to me. Do you have an example of one of your test cases where you feel uncomfortable with? (The usage of `verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockDep);` _can_ be debatable, but it depends on the tested subject).

Comment: Unit testing is gray/white box testing. It should never be used as black box testing. Its purpose is to test all the logic of the class in test including how it interacts with its dependencies. The mock helps avoiding testing any of dependency code.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you want to verify an interaction or stub a call. It's normally a bad sign if you find yourself doing both.

In this case, for example, you wish to stub behaviour. If your mock is not called, then the answer will be wrong, there's no requirement to ensure that your stub has been called.

If you want to be sure no other interactions have occurred, I recommend enabling strict mode (https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#40).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on logic which you're testing. Since your example don't provide any context, I'll give you a case when I feel not only comfortable to test such interaction, but even mandatory:

Let's say you're testing authentication token validation. You pas some token to your validator and it returns `true`/`false`. Inside of your validator you're calling some `jwt.validate` or any other 3rd party hash validation method. In this case I need to know that this validator will be called every time, because I can introduce some `if token == null` condition inside which will bypass this validation call and just return false. Then your tests could still pass but your code is now vulnerable to timing attack.

It's one kind of example. The other type of test I'm comfortable of testing that way is so called `border testing`. I want to know that my class triggers stripe payment gateway - so I mock it and just make sure it gets called without checking anything sophisticated in this particular test.